# jqGrid with Bootstrap 4? What has to be changed in CSS?

Tags: jqgrid

The functionality of JQGrid is fine with the jquery 3.2.1. However, the styles are off. Can anyone suggest what to change in CSS to render the grid properly?
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is mentioned?

Comment: [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) supports Bootstrap 4. One need just use `guiStyle: "bootstrap4"` instead of `guiStyle: "bootstrap"`. Bootstrap 4 is supported starting with version 4.0.0-alpha.6.

Comment: Oleg, I'm using the latest free version of jqgrid and bootstrap beta1. Is it possible to make jqgrid look like a bootstrap table? In my case all headers and rows and very thin. My goal is to make it look like striped datatable, with the same default heights/widths/styles. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: In my opinion it is good to wait for the final release of Bootstrap 4. Any attempts to make this work in alpha or beta will cause to double work - my two cents

Comment: I did apply ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css instead of ui.jqgrid.css and it looks perfect. However, the font awesome icons to close forms/grid are off. I think a minimum fix will make it perfect. Please let me know if you have an idea how to make it work.

Comment: The Bootstrap 4 official version was released last week. Do you have any estimate on when the JQGrid will support the new version of bootstrap? Thank you

Comment: @Oleg Many people end up on this searching for bootstrap 4 example. Is there anything online that can be linked on this as answer or in comments.

Comment: @FarrukhSubhani: Look at [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap4_code) for example and the corresponding [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/07ousnfk/).